# Shell script not running as expected

Tags: sh, freebsd

**Original Post**

I have pfSense 23.01 with FreeBSD 14.0

On the command line, this works fine.

```
sh
sudo easyrule block lan 192.168.1.20 ; sudo easyrule block lan 192.168.1.21 ;
```

If I run the same command in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo easyrule block lan 192.168.1.20 ; sudo easyrule block lan 192.168.1.21 ;
```

It only runs the first command (.20) and completely ignores the second one (.21).

What am I doing wrong?

*PS: I have tinkered with some scripts in bash on Ubuntu, but don't have any experience with FreeBSD or sh. Not sure if this is a pfSense question, or a shell script question.*

**Update #1**

Following @shellter's advice, I tried putting the commands on separate lines in the script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo easyrule block lan 192.168.1.20 ;
sudo easyrule block lan 192.168.1.21 ;
```

That worked. Now I am faced with the next problem. How do I construct a string variable by concatenating multiple strings, which eventually need to run the command. I tried the following.
The below only runs the first line

```
command=$command" sudo easyrule block lan 192.168.1.20 ;\n"
command=$command" sudo easyrule block lan 192.168.1.21 ;"
$command
```

The below also runs only the first line

```
command=$command" sudo easyrule block lan 192.168.1.20 ;"$'\n'
command=$command" sudo easyrule block lan 192.168.1.21 ;"
$command
```

This one doesn't run anything.

```
command=$command" sudo easyrule block lan 192.168.1.20 ;"$'\n'
command=$command" sudo easyrule block lan 192.168.1.21 ;"
"$command"
```

*PS: I could probably install bash and make this work, but Netgate / pfSense doesn't recommend it (for it potentially introduces an additional attack vector). Since this is a critical security node, I am not comfortable taking the risk - no matter how small*

Comment: Try putting each `;` delimited section on a separate line. Yes, you're right, it should require that, but if it works on separate lines, then you have some new information. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. It does work on separate lines. Though since I am concatenating an arbitrary number of commands at run time, I am still struggling to get it right. I will add information to the question to that effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)

Comment: In short, don't store commands in string variables.

Comment: Thank you @tripleee. I think the recommendation to not store commands in a string is a sound one. Though in my setup I don't have access to arrays. The other solution recommended on that post (eval) does work fine for my use case.

Comment: If you don't have Bash, you also don't have `$'\n'`. Perhaps see also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: From what inputs are you constructing the command? The simplest by far would be something like `for ip in 192.168.1.20 192.168.1.21; do sudo easyrule block lan "$ip"; done` or perhaps `printf '%s\n' 192.168.1.20 192.168.1.21 | while read -r ip; do sudo easyrule block lan "$ip"; done`

Comment: @triplee, thank you. To answer your question, it is a utility script for me (or others with su access). The script takes in parameters like "blockdevices.sh -atr" and depending on the options chosen, it collects all the IPs that need to be blocked (anywhere between 1 to 100). With "eval" I was concatenating all commands and executing. With your suggestions (both work), I can concatenate all the IPs in a string and run a loop at the end. I can see how in general use cases your recommendation is a lot more secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of any future readers who do not have access to bash. Say only sh on FreeBSD (which does not link to bash).

Based on @tripleee's suggestion and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia) answer, there are two options available to you.

**Option 1** (dangerous. **Only** use if you have complete control over the string)

```
eval $command
```

or

**Option 2** (better overall)

```
for ip in $command;
  do sudo easyrule block lan "$ip";
done
```